# Python Mechanize - unescape_charref() can't deal with hex code

Tags: python, escaping, mechanize

I've encountered an interesting error in Mechanize, of which I'm unsure to submit it as a bug, or need to look for a workaround.

Opening a page that (erroneously?) contains an escaped character with a hex code, causes a ValueError. The following code reproduces the error:

```
import mechanize
b = mechanize.Browser()
gr = 'http://www.goodreads.com/'
b.open(gr + 'book/show/613791.Santuario_De_La_Pen_X303_A_De_Francia')
```

After a long Traceback, the following is reported:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mechanize\_html.py", line 317, in unescape_charref
  uc = unichr(int(name, base))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'X303'
```

I guess this is caused by unescape_charref() expecting a binary character code (e.g. #771), where this page uses the hex code #X303. Is there a way to let Mechanize handle this properly?

I'm actually not too concerned with proper unescaping in this case, since I only want to retrieve an URL from inside the head element of such pages. I would like to catch the ValueError and just continue with getting the response. Unfortunately Mechanize can't deal with this and returns None.

Answer (score 0):

You should report it.

In the short term you could modify that line in the source file to something like this:

```
try:
    uc = unichr(int(name, base))
except ValueError:
    if base == 10 and name[0].lower() == "x":
        uc = unichr(int(name[1 : ], 16))
    else:
        raise
```